# TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My problame is when I add a comments to any post i get this Error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of null`

Post routs :

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);

  Post.findById(req.params.post_id, (e, post) => {
    if (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } else {
      Comment.create(
        { content: req.body.content, image: req.body.image },
        (e, comment) => {
          if (e) {
            console.log(e);
          } else {
            post.comments.push(comment);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

Post schema

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: String,
  image: String,
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comment",
    },
  ],
});
```

when I look inside the db I could see this results.

```
{
    "comments": [],
    "_id": "5ed97ccbfb6e4c7b8482a595",
    "content": "Azooz",
    "image": "dsadasda",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve it..

Comment: Are you sure findById is finding a post?  console.log(post) might provide a clue.

Comment: console.log(post) = Null :) Why ?

Comment: What does console.log(req.params.post_id) say?  Perhaps post_id doesn't match any posts.

Comment: when i write console.log(req.params.post_id); it says = undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution , I'm using express router and if i need to access the post_id from comments route I should set the mergeParams to true ,

Before

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
```

After

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

What is mergeParams? 
Preserve the req.params values from the parent router. If the parent and the child have conflicting param names, the child’s value take precedence.

For more Click [Here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router)

Answer (score 0):

When post not found the post value will be null. so please make sure the post value is not null.